# Jasmine: scoping issues on tesing promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm experiencing some issues with Jasmine. I'm kinda a newbie, so it's probably not a smart question.

I have a $http.get service written in AngularJS:

```
app.service('commissionSvc', ['$http', function ($http) {
this.getCommissionList = function (token) {
    if (!token)
        throw Error('missing token')
    else {
        var config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': "application/json",
                'Authorization': "Bearer" + token
            }
        };
        return $http.get(apiURL + '/commission/', config)
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            })
    }
}
}]);
```

and I want to test in Jasmine whether or not I'm getting in then or catch:

```
    ....*code code code* ....
    it('should be in catch on errors', function () {
        httpBackend.expectGET(apiURL + '/commission/').respond(401, '');
        var whereAmI;

        commissionSvc.getCommissionList('token')
            .then(function(data){
               whereAmI = 'then'
            })
            .catch(function(error){
                whereAmI = 'catch'
           })

        expect(whereAmI).toEqual('catch');
        httpBackend.flush();
    });
    ....* code code code *....
```

The problem is that inside the *then* and the *catch* functions the variable `whereAmI` is undefined and I am unable to conclude the test.

Is there a way to pass the variable to the then/catch functions?
Is it the right way to unit-test such behavior of this service?

Thank you,

Manuel

**ANSWER**

As suggested in comments, switching the last two lines in my test was enough. Hence the test looks like:

```
    ....*code code code* ....
    it('should be in catch on errors', function () {
        httpBackend.expectGET(apiURL + '/commission/').respond(401, '');
        var whereAmI;

        commissionSvc.getCommissionList('token')
            .then(function(data){
               whereAmI = 'then'
            })
            .catch(function(error){
                whereAmI = 'catch'
           })
        httpBackend.flush();          
        expect(whereAmI).toEqual('catch');
      });
    ....* code code code *....
```

Comment: I believe you should run `httpBackend.flush()` before the expectation to resolve the mocked HTTP request. Then you *may* (please experiment) need to run a digest to resolve the chained promises as well.

Comment: Hello, Nikos! Switching the last two lines in my test did the trick, there has been no need to run a `$digest` cycle. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please do update the question with the answer for others to see. It might be helpful to them.